# adding a comma and "" to a specific text

Tags: r, regex

I don't know what category my question falls into. I have a text that has a pattern like below.

> 1 MERRILL LYNCH 33 2 LEHMAN BROTHERS HLDGS. 82 3 SALOMON 149 4 PAINE
>   WEBBER GROUP 248 5 BEAR STEARNS 328 6 CHARLES SCHWAB 621 7 A.G.
>   EDWARDS & SONS 823

The pattern is (sequence from 1, a company name (consists of characters or numbers), number (maximum 1000)) repeated

I want to (build a function) that turns this text into a vector;

```
c("1 MERRILL LYNCH 33", "2 LEHMAN BROTHERS HLDGS. 82", "3 SALOMON 149", 
  "4 PAINE WEBBER GROUP 248", "5 BEAR STEARNS 328", "6 CHARLES SCHWAB 621", 
  "7 A.G. EDWARDS & SONS 823")
```

Would this be possible? There's no regularity in the company name or the number that follows. There's always a space after the first increasing sequence, a space after a company name. I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: The number after the company, is it always a block of digits only (123, not 12 3 or 12.3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `stringr` package,

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(txt, "[0-9]+\\D+[0-9]+")
```

The regular expression reads 'any number of digits', then 'anything except digits', then 'any number of digits'.

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "1 MERRILL LYNCH 33"          "2 LEHMAN BROTHERS HLDGS. 82" "3 SALOMON 149"              
[4] "4 PAINE WEBBER GROUP 248"    "5 BEAR STEARNS 328"          "6 CHARLES SCHWAB 621"       
[7] "7 A.G. EDWARDS & SONS 823"
```

Note that the result is  a list.

Answer (score 2):

Analogous to @Remeko Duursma's answer, here is the base R version:

```
regmatches(txt, gregexpr("[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]+", txt))[[1]]
```

Results:

```
[1] "1 MERRILL LYNCH 33"          "2 LEHMAN BROTHERS HLDGS. 82"
[3] "3 SALOMON 149"               "4 PAINE WEBBER GROUP 248"   
[5] "5 BEAR STEARNS 328"          "6 CHARLES SCHWAB 621"       
[7] "7 A.G. EDWARDS & SONS 823"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another option is `strsplit` from `base R`

```
strsplit(txt, "(?<=[0-9])\\s+(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "1 MERRILL LYNCH 33"          "2 LEHMAN BROTHERS HLDGS. 82" "3 SALOMON 149" 
#[4] "4 PAINE WEBBER GROUP 248" "5 BEAR STEARNS 328"  "6 CHARLES SCHWAB 621"
#[7] "7 A.G. EDWARDS & SONS 823"
```

---

Or another `base R` option would be with `gsub` and `scan`

```
scan(text = gsub("(\\d+) (\\d+)", "\\1,\\2", txt), what = "", sep=",", quiet = TRUE)
#[1] "1 MERRILL LYNCH 33"          "2 LEHMAN BROTHERS HLDGS. 82" "3 SALOMON 149"             
#[4] "4 PAINE WEBBER GROUP 248"  "5 BEAR STEARNS 328"   
#[6]   "6 CHARLES SCHWAB 621"        "7 A.G. EDWARDS & SONS 823"
```